# C# - Round float every time down

Tags: c#, rounding

How to round a floating point number each time to nearest integer, but only down way. I need the fastest method.

So that float 1.2 will be 1 and 1.8 will be 1 too.

**1.2f** will be **1.0f**

**1.8f** will be **1.0f**

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the result to be of type float or int?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Math.Floor()](http://www.dotnetperls.com/math-floor) is your friend here.

Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace math
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //
            // Two values.
            //
            float value1 = 123.456F;
            float value2 = 123.987F;
            //
            // Take floors of these values.
            //
            float floor1 = (float)Math.Floor(value1);
            float floor2 = (float)Math.Floor(value2);

            //
            // Write first value and floor.
            //
            Console.WriteLine(value1);
            Console.WriteLine(floor1);
            //
            // Write second value and floor.
            //
            Console.WriteLine(value2);
            Console.WriteLine(floor2);

            return;        
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

By casting to an int, you will truncate the decimals

```
float f = 1.2;
int rounded = (int)f;
```

Comment: This will _truncate_ the decimals, as you correctly say. That means it will be rounding up not down if the number is negative.

Answer (score 2):

`System.Math.Floor(double)` should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

```
Math.Ceiling(value)
Math.Floor(value); //your answer
```

Answer (score 1):

OP asked for the fastest way. Casting to int rounds towards zero so depending on the range you can add a value to make it positive, cast to an int and subtract the same value eg.

```
float a = -5.2f;
float b = (int)(a + 1000) - 1000;

// b = -6.0f
```

I did some benchmarks and this method is at least twice as fast as using Math.Floor().

- Math.Floor() is just as fast now it seems.